# How to compile lines with a certain word in the last column into a separate file?

Tags: linux, files, filter

I have a csv file and I need to filter it out into two files based on whether the last column contains the word "ecDNA". I already have two more copies of the file to edit without changing the original file. Is there any way I can delete all the lines that do not contain "ecDNA" from one file and only retain lines that contain "ecDNA" from another copy of the file?

Comment: Please edit your question to include minimal working input file and how you are trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk -F, '$NF ~ /ecDNA/' oldfile > newfile
```

NF is the number of fields (columns) on the current input line, so $NF is the value (contents) of the last field.   If $NF contains "ecDNA", then print the the line.  Otherwise, ignore it.

If you need the match to be case-insensitive (and you're using GNU awk), use:

```
awk -F, -v IGNORECASE=1 '$NF ~ /ecDNA/' oldfile > newfile
```

For the inverted match (lines without `ecDNA` in the last field), negate the condition operator:

```
awk -F, '$NF !~ /ecDNA/' oldfile > newfile2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! Sorry for not replying.

Comment: @MichelleYang. If this worked, you may accept the answer.